# how to send url request with xml to php page

Tags: php, ios, iphone, objective-c, post

```
NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" ?>\n<url><loc>http://www.abc.co.uk/index.php</loc><lastmod>2014-02-08</lastmod><changefreq>Monthly</changefreq><priority>0.9</priority></url>"];

NSString *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mypath.co.uk/ifo.xml"];
NSMutableURLRequest *Request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[Request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[Request setValue:@"application/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[Request setHTTPBody:[message dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSError *Error = nil;
NSLog(@"%@Post message", message);
Status.text = message;
_Connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:Request delegate:self];
if(_Connection)
{
    NSLog(@"Connection Build");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Connection error...");
    NSLog(@"%@",Error);
}
```

---

Anyone who use this please figure out the problem here.

On button click the request method is called.

Thanks in advance.

`NSLog` : shows the error

```
NSURL length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x89dac30
2014-02-14 15:55:26.513 eAgent[2369:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSURL length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x89dac30'
```

Comment: Sorry I'm not a PHP programmer so could be a stupid question, but the URL you are trying to POST to  ends with `ifo.xml` - are you trying to create that file or should there be some PHP code, that takes the body and write it to a file

Comment: @Flexicoder You are correct, the HTTP request should be made to a PHP file which will then process whatever it is sent (which I guess is XML).

Comment: oh yes i have to send it to .php page….

Comment: @Flexicoder thanks … and yes some time we stuck on that type of little problem

Comment: @Nick thanks man let me check with the right .php extention

Comment: The error message you're seeing states simply that you're sending the message `length` to an object which does not respond to it, `NSURL`. However that error is not stemming from the code you've written. Where do you send the message `length` to an `NSURL`?

Comment: @PeterFoti i am not sending the message length, and that all code i am using.

Comment: @user3228895 the answer is below, at run time it was calling `length` on an `NSURL` because it was made to believe it was an `NSString`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is:

```
NSString *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mypath.co.uk/ifo.xml"];
NSMutableURLRequest *Request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
```

`URLWithString` is a `NSURL` class method and it returns an `NSURL` not an `NSString`. Change that and in the request use the resultant `NSURL` object and the errors will go away.

Like so:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mypath.co.uk/ifo.xml"];
NSMutableURLRequest *Request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
```

Comment: yes it resolve the issue…. Thanks a lot…. i love you.

Comment: I appreciate I overlooked the fact that you were trying to create a NSString instance, and not a NSURL, however how come it is now working (sending to a URL with ifo.xml)?